# Imagen de background en PDF creado con FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Esto haciendo un archivo PDF según la consulta de MySql y PHP con FPDF, todo me resulta bien y el archivo pdf se crea sin problema, de hecho le puse una imagen de fondo para que se vea mejor y se ve muy bien, el problema viene cuando se crea una segunda página, la imagen de fondo no se pone y se pone en blanco, les comparto el codigo para que lo vean y me puedan ayudar para que se vea el background en la segunda página

De hecho, como verán, intente ponerlo en un Header pero no me funciona, de antemano gracias por la ayuda

```
<?php

require('fpdf/WriteHTML.php');
require('conexion.php');
//Rece-On6zpy
// Rece-fyR9Bc

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM recetas WHERE codigo='Rece-
On6zpy'"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Cabecera de página
function Header()
{
    $this->Image('images/4.jpg', 0, 0, 250, 300);
// Movernos a la derecha
$this->Cell(80);
// Título
$this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
// Salto de línea
$this->Ln(20);
}
function Footer(){
// Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
$this->SetY(-15);
// Arial italic 8
$this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
// Número de página
$this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}

}

$pdf = new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AddPage('','','Letter');
//$pdf->Image('images/4.jpg', 0, 0, 250, 300);
$pdf->Image('images/logo3.png',50,10, 30,30);
$pdf->Image('images/logo3.png',130,10, 30,30);
$ruta ="photos_recetas_master/". $row['foto'];
$pdf->Image($ruta, 150, 55, 40, 40);
$pdf->Ln(30);
$pdf->Cell(150, 10, '', 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Fecha: '.date('d-m-Y').'', 0);
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 11);
$pdf->Cell(70, 8, '', 0);
$pdf->Cell(100, 8, 'RECETA DE ARKACHEF.COM', 0);
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->Cell(45, 8, 'Nombre de la receta :', 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(150, 8, $row['nombre'], 0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->Cell(45, 8, 'Rinde para :', 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(25, 8, $row['num_personas'].' personas', 0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->Cell(45, 8, 'Tipo de comida :', 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(30, 8, $row['tipo_comida'], 0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$str = utf8_decode('Clasificación');
$pdf->Cell(45, 8, $str.' de comida :', 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(37, 8, $row['clasi_gastro'], 0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->Cell(23, 8, 'Ingredientes', 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$str2= html_entity_decode($row['ingredientes']);
$str2= ltrim($str2," ");
$pdf-> WriteHTML(utf8_decode($str2),0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->Ln();
$str = utf8_decode('Preparación');
$pdf->Cell(45, 8, $str, 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$str3= html_entity_decode($row['preparacion']);
$pdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($str3),1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->Cell(23, 8, 'Comentarios', 0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$str4= html_entity_decode($row['comentarios']);
$pdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($str4),1);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Tendrías que añadir una nueva página con el método AddPage.

Answer (score 0):

intenta con estos parametros en tu codigo donde pones la imagen en el header:

```
$this->Image('images/4.jpg', 0, 0, 250, 300,'','', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
```

responde si funciono

Comment: Saludos, tu respuesta poddría mejorarse si explicas que es lo que estas haciendo con ese código que propones. ;)